# How ensure that user lands scrolled down to the section of the page as shown in Google's featured snippet or description?

Tags: seo, google, rich-snippets

I have observed that google picks content from our page and shows it as a featured snippet. But once the user opens the link, the content in the featured snippet is at the bottom which would make it very difficult for the user to discover the content.

How can we solve this problem? Is there any way by which we can ask google to scroll down to the featured snippet content?

The link shown in the snapshot is [this](https://www.bikewale.com/royalenfield-bikes/classic-350/).

[image]

Comment: I am not ware of anything you can do to help the user. This is a Google weakness. A reasonably simple mechanism could be standardized to make this happen, but as of now, Google and websites would all have to participate. You may be stuck. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is a way to force a user to jump to a particular part of the content on your page. In fact, Google has answer boxes for its own content and does not do that. For example, search "where is indexing in Google search console", click the link, and it takes you to the top of the top page; however, the answer is past the fold.

Nevertheless, a creative way to provide a positive user experience is by adding jump links to the top of the page so that a user can easily navigate to the answer that you provide or you can edit your content so that it is closer to the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

There *is* a feature that does exactly what you describe, but it all happens on Google's end.

It's also, in my experience, most prevalent right now for question/answer based queries.

Very often in fact, I'll click the link shown in answer box and it takes me directly to the corresponding section with the answer box text highlighted in yellow.

Structured data *could* have something to do with this, but I think it's doubtful at least right now.

More likely than not, aside from tagging our content, we were training early iterations of this functionality when we used Google's [Data Highlighter](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2692911).